# ios How to changed the upper keyboard bar color and button color?

Tags: xcode, button, colors, keyboard

How to changed the upper keyboard bar color and button color?

I set the textfield delegate .

Then the keyboard show the bar, I need change the bar color and button.

But I don't know how to set.

Have any one can help me?  thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1.Add A Notification for Keyboard to no if the keyboard is will (did) show**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(liftMainViewWhenKeybordAppears:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

}

**2.Then in liftMainViewWhenKeybordAppears: method, You can change the Bar Color and Buton.**

```
- (void)liftMainViewWhenKeybordAppears:(NSNotification *)notice{

   yourBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   [yourButton setTitle:@"newTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

**3.Remove Notification**

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

}